# Unexpected Firebase Firestore collection subscription behaviour

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am experiencing some interesting behaviour regarding a subscription on a collection's valueChanges.

Immediately after creating a doc, the collection's subscription is invoked, but **instead of an array of many documents I am only receiving an array of size one** - the single, newly created document.

After having a read through this [(Firestore Docs | Get Realtime Updates)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) I am still slightly confused.

> Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners immediately. This is because of an important feature called "latency compensation." When you perform a write, your listeners will be notified with the new data before the data is sent to the backend.

Does this explain the behaviour I am seeing?

---

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firebase-subscription-test) demonstrating the problem. Just uncomment out the commented line in ngOnInit() and reload to see what I believe is expected behaviour.

---

*I can solve this by either having an empty subscription listening to this collection elsewhere, or duplicating the take(1) subscription code directly before*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a good catch. Pretty sure you are right - `valueChanges()` as docs states:

> The current state of your collection. Returns an Observable of data as
>   a synchronized array of JSON objects.

And as you found yourself:

> Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners immediately.

So this is what happens:

Your `addPizza()` is an **async** function. It sends request to backed to add new pizza. But it doesnt wait for anything and jumps to your second function - `this.getPizzasAsyncAwait()`. And because that local write invokes listener immediately, your Observable emits that value and broadcasts it. And since you also use Rxjs's `take(1)` - after that it unsubscribes. That also explains why `take(2)` brings all other records. You can move your `getPizzasNormal()` method to `OnInit()` and you'll receive the whole collection.

Comment: Yup, this unfortunately seems to be the case. Been wrestling with this exact behaviour over the past few days as I am trying to reduce the number of subscriptions and firebase calls I am making. But is sort of seems to be necessary to keep that normal subscription (with limit(1) to reduce firebase reads) in you ngOnInits. Thanks for the help @J.D.

Comment: I think `take(2)` in such case - when you subscribe at the same type you add, is considered as a ok way to go. As @ibenjelloun seems to be well versed about the topic, but using Promise's callback might have a side effect - you wont subscribe if it doesn't resolve. Of course you can `catch()`that, but compared to `take(2)`, it seems a bit too heavy.

Answer (score 1):

The firebase js sdk handles optimistically the add, before getting the collection values, the collection is not defined yet. Once you add a value the collection contains 1 value and then is updated by the server side values.

If you want to avoid getting this intermediate state when the collection values are set only from local changes, you can subscribe before start changes to be done before subscribing :

```
this.piazzaRef.add({
   name: name,
   addedAt: new Date().toISOString()
}).then(() => {
   this.getPizzasAsyncAwait();
   this.getPizzasNormal();
});
```

[I updated your example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49630053)